# Can't understand why my variable doesn't change

Tags: vb.net

I'm building a little time > pay conversion program in VB. I'm really new to VB and don't understand why my variable pay doesn't calculate like it should. I plug in 5 5's as a test and get $0.

```
Dim total As Double = 0.0
Dim timeCounter As Integer = 0
Dim time As Integer = 0
Dim pay As Double = 0.0

While timeList.Items.Count < 5
    time = timeList.Items(timeCounter)
    total += time
    timeCounter += 1
End While

If total >= 0 And total <= 40 Then
    If total >= 0 And total <= 20 Then
        pay = total * 10
    ElseIf total >= 21 And total <= 30 Then
        pay = total * 12
    ElseIf total >= 31 And total <= 40 Then
        pay = total * 15
    Else
        PayLabel.Text = "Error"
    End If
End If

PayLabel.Text = "$" & pay
```

Comment: From what I can see here - your while loop must not be being entered. Rendering the value of total = 0. Then all of your multiplication functions are multiplying by 0 causing the result to be 0.

Comment: Try setting total = 1. I'm willing to bet the answer comes out at 10.

Comment: what is timeList? how many item is in it when you run it?

Comment: @ninn you are correct the output is $10, so why isn't my loop being entered?

Comment: @Fredou timeList is a listbox with the times entered into the textbox. After the timeList gets 5 times entered, it locks for further input.

Comment: you also need to do something to make sure that you increase the items.count in the loop or it will be a infinite loop, your count must be over 5

Comment: Ok just changed the while loop count to 6 and it broke the computer. So I guess my syntax for my loop is wrong. How do I say
{while(timeList<6) do this}

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do - but using a while loop for this is not correct. Try looking into for loops.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Visual_Basic_For_Loops

Comment: your loop will also only process the first 4 items in the listbox, if that is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax should be something like this:

```
For intCount = 0 To timeList.Items.Count
    time = timeList.Items(intCount)
    total += time
Next intCount
```

This will avoid an infinite loop.

To fix your 40+ issue:

```
If total >= 0 And total <= 40 Then
    If total >= 0 And total <= 20 Then
        pay = total * 10
    ElseIf total >= 21 And total <= 30 Then
        pay = total * 12
    ElseIf total >= 31 And total <= 40 Then
        pay = total * 15
    End If
Else
    PayLabel.Text = "Error"            
End If
```

Comment: i always assumed not to assume anything, maybe he really want to process only the first 4 items of the list? your solution process all of them

Comment: ^^good point. He also said that the timeList is a ListBox object. Does it really make sense to use a while loop when processing an unpredicted amount of items created by User input?

Comment: it should add all 5 entries in the list. When i replaced the while loop with your for loop, I still break the program.

Comment: Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'

Comment: @SkyVar, you should turn on strict ON and explicit ON in the project properties, listbox contain string and you are adding them to a number, this will be catch by these setting

Comment: @SkyVar, For intCount = 0 To timeList.Items.Count -1 will fix that issue

Comment: @SkyVar ^^this is correct. "turn on strict ON and explicit ON in the project properties" would be the best fix. Otherwise, "For intCount = 0 To timeList.Items.Count -1" works as a solution. Fredou - +1s!

Comment: @Fredou im looking in the properties for the listbox and don't see any option for strict or explicit. I'm using VS express 2012 desktop

Comment: @SkyVar, properties of the project, not listbox. right click on the project file in the solution explorer, go to compile tab on your left

Comment: Well that fixed the issue for the most part, but when I type in numbers out of the range of 40 I don't get the error message like I expected or I wrote in the if statement

Comment: because of " If total >= 0 And total <= 40 Then", you will never get to your error.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark the question resolved by choosing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

this would be my fix into a console apps

for process will return $0, second $100

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim timeList As New List(Of Integer)

    timeList.AddRange(New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})
    process(timeList)
    timeList.Clear()
    timeList.AddRange(New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4})
    process(timeList)

    Console.Read()


End Sub

Private Sub process(timeList As List(Of Integer))
    Dim total As Double = 0.0
    Dim timeCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim time As Integer = 0
    Dim pay As Double = 0.0
    While timeList.Count < 5 AndAlso timeCounter < timeList.Count
        time = timeList(timeCounter)
        total += time
        timeCounter += 1
    End While

    If total >= 0 And total <= 40 Then
        If total >= 0 And total <= 20 Then
            pay = total * 10
        ElseIf total >= 21 And total <= 30 Then
            pay = total * 12
        ElseIf total >= 31 And total <= 40 Then
            pay = total * 15
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("error")
        End If
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("$" & pay)
End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be better solved with a functional approach.  To get the sum of the list of integers do the following:

```
Dim totalTime = timeList.Sum()
```

Then you can follow the logic you laid out. I would highly recommend learning to use Linq Set Functions to make your code your readable and easier to understand.  Good Luck.